# How to download files from HTTP in Symbian C++?

Tags: c++, http, download, symbian

I need to download file from HTTP in Symbian C++. Can somebody tell me, how I can do this, couse I cannot find it in Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [HTTP Client Example](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/5ab5b21c-12fa-48dc-97c4-f9b6cce0a6ba/S60_Platform_HTTP_Client_Example_v2_2_en.zip.html) on Forum Nokia.